# NodeJS lineReader appendFile -- lines get lost somewhere

Tags: node.js, sha1

I have a script that is running fine with on my local computer using a 10 line test file. However, when I use the script in AWS with the real file, which is **20 million lines**, I seem to lose 1/5th of the lines. What am I doing wrong in this script? I am receiving no error messages.

```
var sha1 = require('sha1');

var fs = require('fs');

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    terminal: false,
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('./readme.txt')
});

    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {

        var hashed = sha1(line);

        fs.appendFile('./writeme.txt', line + "," + hashed + "\n", function(err){

    })

});
```

Comment: Try use appendFileSync instead, if you are not comfortable with async terminology

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked. Thank you event-stream and the Transform option!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');
var es = require('event-stream');
var sha1 = require('sha1');

var input = fs.createReadStream("readme.txt");
var output = fs.createWriteStream("writeme.txt");

var parse = new stream.Transform;

parse._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {

var hashed = sha1(chunk);
var line = chunk + ' | ' + hashed + '\n';

    done(null, line);
}

input.pipe(es.split('\n')).pipe(parse).pipe(output);
```